# How do I include a class from a package in another location

Tags: java, compilation, package, javac

I have a Stack.java file stored in

```
C:\Users\Aaditya\Documents\Github\Data Structures\com\stack\Stack.java
```

In the declaration of the file, I have given this

```
package com.stack;
```

So, now I have a Parantheses.java file stored in

```
C:\Users\Aaditya\Documents\Github\Data Structures\Parantheses\Parantheses.java
```

And now when I have the below code in this file, and subsequently I compile it,

```
import com.stack.*;
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\Aaditya\Documents\GitHub\Data Structures\Parantheses>javac *.java
Parantheses.java:1: error: package com.stack does not exist
import com.stack.*;
^
```

Can anyone sort this error out for me.

**PS:**
When I put all the java files in one folder and then compile them (without the 'import' and 'package' thing), I dont get any error. Program runs succesfully.

Thanks. :)

Comment: You will have to include both these directories to your sourcepath while compiling.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/toc.html) Oracle tutorial, especially "Setting the Class Path".

Answer (score 0):

Try using -sourcepath while using javac which will allow you to include files from different location.

Links :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#CBHHCGFB

On the other hand better way to manage dependencies is maven.

Comment: Now when I run **javac *.java -classpath "..\Stack" com.stack** , I get this error **error: Class names, 'com.stack', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested**